# Sending e-mails to contacts

Tags: email, apex-email-service, massemailmessage

My org have a lot of contacts - around 2000. All of these contacts have e-mail address. I need to send an e-mail to each of them.
An admin will enter a body (on a VF page) and click "send e-mails" button.
The question is will this work?
In [General Email Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_general.htm&language=en_US) is a note

> There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your organization directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object pages.

So is it a case? Can I send 2000 e-mail to my contacts (one e-mail to each contact)?

What should be written in controller?
I found [MassEmailMessage Methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm#apex_classes_email_outbound_mass). There is a [setTargetObjectIds(ID[])](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm#apex_Messaging_MassEmailMessage_setTargetObjectIds) method. But I'm not sure what does

> All email must have a recipient value of at least one of the following:
>   toAddresses
>   ccAddresses
>   bccAddresses
>   targetObjectId
>   targetObjectIds

mean.
Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use SetTargetID method with ID array patameter as the contact Ids .The email limits wont apply if you use SetTargetID method .Dont use toaddress method onstead use setTargetId .

Using setTargetId method email limit wont count against governor limit

Comment: That is it what I thought about sending e-mails to contacts. Thanks!

Comment: Mark the answer as answered if that helped

Comment: I will after I prove this concept. I didn't have a chance to check this.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Are you sure? Because when I tried MassEmailMessage and SingleEmailMessage limit started reflecting and both mass email and single email started reducing.

Comment: Ya its documented below in the limit guide http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/15/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: check under Email Limits section